# How to get just first(datetime2 data type) value form each date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have SQL query for filtering working time of employees. Actually I need to create a report(using visual studio reports) that displays arrival time for every employee and for each day in month. In my SQL I have a few records(arrival time) for the same date. Only I want to do is to show just first arrival time, not second and further. I called that column Start_Session as datetime2 type.
How can I filter it, is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Do you have duplicate rows or just several that you need the first of?

Comment: @Larnu I tried that already, but in this case it isn't solution. When I write SELECT TOP 1 FROM table_name, my report doesn't have any records, I don't now why.

Comment: @iamdave That isn't duplicates because I have different time for same date. For example, I have 2020-10-10 07:50:34 and 2020-10-10 07:57:23. Query shows me both, but I want just first, earlier time. But is it possible, because it is datetime2?

Comment: *"When I write SELECT TOP 1 FROM table_name, my report doesn't have any records"* then there are no rows in the table. `TOP 1` doesn't filter the rows, just limits the number.

Comment: @Larnu Result of query is empty.

Comment: Yes, so the table `table_name` has no rows. @red_devil . `SELECT * FROM table_name` and `SELECT TOP (1) * FROM Table_name` will only return 0 rows if `table_name` has no rows. If the first returns rows, the second will return a single row.

Comment: I want to display first(one) value for each employee.

Comment: @Larnu If you want I can post screenshot of my report. So you can clearly see it.

Comment: @Larnu Please actually take the time to engage with the people you speak with on here.  You are running down a rabbit hole over how `top 1` works because the OP didn't actually read the answers in the question you linked, but responded to the text of your link.  This is a misunderstanding that you have missed by moving too quickly and adds nothing but confusion.

Comment: @iamdave if I wasn't engaging with the user, I wouldn't have wrote any comments; by writing a comment I am, by definition, engaging with them... The fact doesn't change they are saying `TOP 1` is causing them to get "no rows" which simply can't happen if the table contains rows.

Comment: @Larnu Which is totally besides the point, as it has nothing to do with the problem in the question.

Comment: No, the answer to the question is in my first comment, @iamdave : [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group). (but how would I know that, I wasn't engaging the OP )

Answer (score 1):

It seems you aren't understanding the other question that Larnu linked you to in the comments.  The answer to that question is not suggesting you want to be using a `top(1)`, but instead filtering for the first row in a defined group.  Per those answers, that can be achieved with the `row_number()` window function.  In your case, this would look something like the following:

```
with r as
(
    select Employee
          ,cast(ArrivalTime as date) as ArrivalDate
          ,ArrivalTime
          ,row_number() over (partition by Employee, cast(ArrivalTime as date) order by ArrivalTime) as rn
    from YourTable
)
select Employee
      ,ArrivalDate
      ,ArrivalTime
from r
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this will help me.

Comment: Your query is useful. But I need to display just one(first) value for each employee. For example I have two different values for same employee. And I want to display just first, earlier value.

Comment: @red_devil  Even if the values are on different days?  At the moment, this query will give you the first `ArrivalTime` value for each `Employee` for each day.  If you only want the first `ArrivalTime` across *all* days, then remove `, cast(ArrivalTime as date)` from the `partition by`.

Comment: I fixed it. It is correct now. I made temporary database and this works. But in my main database I can't use DISTINCT keyword, because I have some attributes that are geography data type. And query can't be executed without DISTINCT. Any help?

Comment: That sounds like a new question.  If this question is answered as you appear to be saying, for the benefit of other users please mark it as the answer and then ask a new question with your `distinct` issue.

Comment: I have problem with DISTINCT again. It doesn't work in my query. I tried GROUP BY but query can't be executed because I have two attributes with geography data type. When I run query SQL display message error that geography data type cannot be used in GROUP clause. @iamdave

Comment: @red_devil  As I said above, please mark this as the answer to the original question and then ask a new question for your `distinct` issue.